# JUnit test NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, nullpointerexception

I write WEB app with Spring, Hibernate, i have CRUD function and i need create test, all the functions of the workers, but the test does not work.

It's my first test with JUnit and i cannot run test successfully, i have `NullPointerException`. I have class controller `Handler.java`, model class `Student.java`.

Here is my code.

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="middleName")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name="groups")
    private String group;

    @Column(name="rating")
    private double average;

    //setter and getter, constructor
```

**Handler.java** - this is controller

```
@Controller
public class Handler {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDataAccessObject studentDAO;

    public void setStudentDAO(StudentDataAccessObject studentDAO) {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }
    /**
     * @param student data from the client
     * @return return new data
     * */
    @RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Student addStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        studentDAO.addStudentToDatabase(student);
        return student;
    }
    ...
}
```

**StudentDataAccessObject.java**

```
public class StudentDataAccessObject implements DatabaseStudent{        
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    /**
     * This method add student to database, use framework Hibernate
     * @param student add to database
     * */
    public void addStudentToDatabase(Student student) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(student);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    ...
}
```

**TestHandler.java** this is test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"Student-servlet.xml"})
public class TestDAO {
    @Test
    public void testHandler(){
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Student student = new Student("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4",4);
        handler.addStudent(student);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Student-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="home.spring.mvc.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/views/**" location="/views/"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student" />
    <property name="username" value="********" />
    <property name="password" value="********" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>home.data.model.student.Student</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="studentDAO" class="home.data.db.dao.StudentDataAccessObject">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Add the exception stacktrace and you can remove all the unnecessary code.

Comment: `DAO` is not a subject of unit tests. It's a subject of integration tests.

Comment: "_i have NullPointerException_" In which file? On what line? Your stacktrace will give you all this information.

Comment: "i have NullPointerException" in line `handler.addStudent(student);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are creating your Handler manually. Spring should create it. Otherwise dependency injection would not work. Without dependency injection your dao will be null. You have two option here either let spring create your handler or create handler yourself but set your dao manually.

Here is an example manual creation that fixes your Null Pointer Exception

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"Student-servlet.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class TestDAO {

   @Autowired
   private DatabaseStudent studentDAO;

    @Test
    public void testHandler(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(studentDAO);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.setStudentDAO(studentDAO);
        Student student = new Student("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4",4);
        handler.addStudent(student);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do I add a dependency?
you need to add a handler for the class?

Comment: @BohdanOlehovich I just added an example. I do not have time to test it, but something like this should fix your problem.

Comment: setStudentDAO that method should do? how to implement?
I realized this setter for the field in the class handler, and this method must set StudentDataAccessObject studentDAO?

Comment: On addStudent method you are accessing studentDao object. On normal run it is set by spring. But on your test, your test context file (Student-servlet.xml) does not create Handler so it could not set studnetDao. You are creating it by using new keyword. No body sets studentDao so it is null. And this causes null pointer exception. I am suggesting to set it to get rid of null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot

Comment: @BohdanOlehovich No problem, but on your next questions, please provide additional info like exception stack trace to get more help and less down vote.

Comment: Okey, i forgot add stack trace, it bad, but you solved problem very quickly, thank you

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down. I would advise not involving spring in unit tests. Wire mocks manually.